# How to protect stored user data: phone numbers?

Tags: database, security, encryption, phone-number, privacy

I want to build an app that is basically a subscription service for text messages.

User submits a phone number via my site. I send them a confirmation text with a key, and if they correctly enter the key, then they are subscribed, and every day thereafter I will send them a text with a particular message until they unsubscribe.

Question: I want to store these phone numbers in a way that I (the developer or storage layer administrator) can't view these phone numbers, to preserve privacy. I can't just stored them hashed, then how does my app read them to send the text message? How do I do this?

Edit: This is both a security and privacy question... I want someone who hacks into my system to not be able to get any of the phone numbers, even if they have full access to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking encryption is your only bet. Your going to have to encrypt the phone numbers but only allow the software/service apps to have access to the key. You could store the key on a off site system and have the app via SSH or SSL retrieve the key store it in memory only. That's not to say the key is 100% safe from the administrators but they are just phone numbers can't image someone spending a-lot of effort for cell numbers.

Comment: Sure, I can encrypt the phone numbers and put the key on another server, but that doesn't stop me (or someone who hacks into my system) from going to that other server and grabbing the key to steal my users' data.

It's true, there's much more sensitive data than phone numbers, but at least for academic purposes, is there a way I can set up my app so that _nobody_ has access to these phone numbers?

Comment: The problem that I see is that if at some point in the process the encrypted number has to be returned to its unencrypted state for transmission of the SMS message. The key to decrypt that file has to be known to the software. That does not me you could not implement a key rotation system that changes the key after each use or at a set rate. The software could create a key at a given interval and encrypt the key for used for the encryption of the numbers. But if you don't write the key some where other then the apps memory you are SOL if that app crashes.

Comment: Yes, those are the problems that I see as well. Just curious as to what the industry standard practice is- do most apps go through this trouble, or do they just store your phone number (or other data, except passwords) in plan text?

Comment: I think many would store the phone numbers in plain text, as they are not credit card numbers (you cannot directly create a profit from stealing them). On the other hand, many persons will agree that they they *are* sensitive. In that case - as others have indirectly pointed out - you need to create *use cases*, then a *threat model* and then implement protection. The final solution will certainly be based on creating limited access to data, and encryption can certainly help with that, especially if information is stored in a database or disk.

Answer (score 4):

When software on the system can decrypt them so can anyone with sufficient access to the system. The best you can do is to reduce the risk by using a dedicated system for the actual messaging part. By making messaging the only thing this system can do you limit the options of hacking into the system. Then by using a public/private key encryption the messaging system would be the only system that needs the decryption key. Systems for actually registering users or changing the phone numbers would only require the encryption key.

Now if you want to protect the decryption key any further you could make this system inaccessible to admins by setting a password no one knows and for good measure you could disable all login methods. Oh and make sure the key only exists in memory NOT ON DISK!

In case this messaging system ever goes down you will need to bring up a new messaging system for which you need the key. So you want to have a copy of they key in a secure location behind multiple locks to which different people have the key. These people then can oversee that key is properly entered into the new system without anyone else making any copies of they key and that afterwards all logins are properly disabled.

Comment: +1, but be careful with public/private key encryption for stuff like phone numbers. Anyone with the _public_ key and the encrypted numbers can make tables of phone numbers and the corresponding encrypted version and use this to figure out who the subscribers are.